# vue js express js image not working in production

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, axios

i have site work fine but when i build vue the images disappear and show this me message :- We're sorry but client doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.

I have repeatedly changed the src of the images from localhost to the ip adress of the vps. This problem has been for more than two days, in which I spent about 16 hours and all solutions failed

Comment: You're using React and Vue here? How do you launch the app? Do you have JS enabled? Please provide more context here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve noscript - doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled when serving a Vue App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55459339/how-to-solve-noscript-doesnt-work-properly-without-javascript-enabled-when-se)

Comment: im using vue js

Comment: no its not i saw it yesterday

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.