# Issue with Vue.js and Laravel project: "We're sorry but project_name doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, production-environment

I have a project that consists of a Vue.js frontend (version 2.6.12) and a Laravel backend (version 9.27.0). When I run the project on my localhost, everything works smoothly and I don't encounter any errors. However, when I deploy the project to production mode, specifically when uploading it to the staging environment on my server, I face an issue.

The problem is that when I try to call APIs or perform certain actions, I receive the following error message on the page: "We're sorry but project_name doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue."

I have already made sure that JavaScript is enabled in the browser, and I have cleared the cache as well. Despite these attempts, the error persists.

I'm seeking assistance in understanding why this issue only occurs when the project is in production mode. Is there something specific to the production environment that could be causing this error? Are there any additional configurations or settings that I need to consider?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions that could help me resolve this issue and ensure that my project runs smoothly in the production environment.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u3Cs.png)

Expected Outcome:
When running the project on the production environment, I expected it to function without any errors and successfully insert data into the database when making API calls.

Actual Outcome:
The project displays the error message "We're sorry but project_name doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled" on the page. Additionally, although the API requests return a status code of 200, the data is not being inserted into the database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hard to tell from the info provided but could be CORS issues. Please show us network request/response headers. Also, could be ad-blocker. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55459339/how-to-solve-noscript-doesnt-work-properly-without-javascript-enabled-when-se