# Maximum call stack size exceeded whe using v-dialog

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component inside a v-dialog that whenever i close and tr opening the dialog a second time i get 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error. When that happens the text fields inside my form simply stop working and i can't type anything anymore.

This is how my component is in my dialog. It ahs a listener for when i want to close the dialog

```
  <v-dialog
    v-model="userFormdialog"
    width="1200"
  >
    <v-card>
      <userForm @closeUserForm="userFormdialog = false"/>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
```

In my component inside the dialog i ahve a form with a few selects and text fields and whenever i want to close it i simply reset the form, it's validation and i emmit the the 'closeUserForm'.

```
finish(){
      this.reset()
      this.resetValidation()
      this.$emit('closeUserForm')
    }
```

this is the only component where this happens so far and i am not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're having circular reference.
Check the name of component **userForm**.
[Similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44520195/vue-js-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error-passing-data-from-parent-to-chi)