# Vue.js Error in nextTick: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" & RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) in Vue.js using a template.

I created a side bar component and importing it to a view where the side bar will be showing. When I add the side bar to the component I will encounter the following errors.

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

> [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

I have tried the solution stated on [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44520195/vue-js-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error-passing-data-from-parent-to-chi), but it doesn't work on my side.

Here is the sample code of my **Sidebar.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <side-bar>
    <template slot="links">
      <side-bar-item
        :link="{
          name: 'Home',
          icon: 'ni ni-shop',
          path: '/widgets'
        }"
      ></side-bar-item>
    </template>
  </side-bar>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "SideBar"
  };
</script>
```

And I am trying to import my sidebar to the **Dashboard.vue** page.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <SideBar />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import SideBar from "@/components/SideBar.vue";

  export default {
    name: "Dashboard",
    components: {
      SideBar
    }
  };
</script>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Vue is trying to recursively use your `SideBar` component since it includes `<side-bar>` (the kebab-cased version of `SideBar`). That probably is not what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is recursion! In Sidebar.vue, you are importing `<side-bar>` again on line 2 (itself), if a component wants to render itself as a child, and that child also wants to render itselfs as a child and so on.. You are going to exceed the maximum call stack size.

Answer (score 0):

This comes as a result of naming the file you intend to import with the same name as the one you’re using. These would cause a recursion, leading to a *maximum* runtime error.